# is there a program that allows us to make the edges of an image look randomly torned?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

How do you make the edges of an image look cut? I'm talking about an image such as the following taken from [this webpage](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Mar/22/Internet-Explorer-Global-Variable-Blow-ups):

[image: Cut image]

The pages look like they are "torn" and it's like it's torn randomly (which looks very good) - does anyone know how to achieve this effect in photoshop?

Of rather, is there a program that allows a *lay-person* to create this sort of image?

Comment: Do you actually require any solution to use Photoshop? If not, what OS are you using?

Comment: nop, i just need it to be do-able by anyone without a sense of design. I'm 32-bit windows vista sp2 home premium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That one could have been done using Faststone capture where it is a "two" click option,  just do the image grab, click edges and select torn, of course the edges are not the same so it could be a different screen capture program.

http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm

[image]

Comment: beautiful solution, though you'll agree it isn't real as in its too nicely *torn*

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not sure what you think a "real" torn screen capture would look like... but maybe [this](http://laptoprepairstockton.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/broken-lcd-screen.jpg) would be a better solution for you? :)

Comment: But in all seriousness, you could easily scan/photograph some _real_ torn paper, and use that edge for your border with a minimum of Photoshop/Gimp work.

Comment: @Flimzy lols ok

Answer (score 1):

That effect can be done in any graphics editing program with basic capabilities.  Cut away the part of the image you don't want, and use a jagged line.  Then add a drop-shadow effect.

Comment: i've really no idea how i could do that and make it look nice (look *really* torn)